# In a uniform circular motion why is centripetal acceleration called acceleration if the speed remains the same?

Tags: acceleration, velocity, vectors, speed, centripetal-force

Centripetal acceleration has a direction towards the center of the rotating object and if the magnitude of the speed of rotation remains same, then why do we call it an centripetal acceleration? Doesn't both the direction and magnitude remain same?

Comment: Centripetal acceleration does not point towards the center of the object, it points towards the center of rotation. For example, if you're on the edge of the merry-go-round, your acceleration vector points to the center. If you think about this, you should realize that in this situation, the directions of both your acceleration and your velocity are constantly changing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly in rotational motion there is a continuous change of velocity vector. Since the direction of linear velocity of the rotating particle change constantly.And we know the rate of change of velocity is acceleration. Here centripetal acceleration is arise due to change of this linear velocity vector.
In another point of view we can explain it. According newton's first law of motion,  an object either remains at rest or continues to move in a straight line at a constant velocity, unless acted upon by an external force. Now when the particle moves in a circular path, it always try to move in a straight line not in a carve path. So for making move in a circular path a constant force directed along the center of the circle is require. This force is called centripetal force and centripetal acceleration is corresponding to this force.

Answer (score 1):

No, the direction of the velocity is constantly changing so that it is always tangent to the circle.

There is another quantity, called angular acceleration, which captures the fact that the rotation around the center is unchanging.  You see angular velocity quoted when people talk about the revolutions per minute of a record player or an engine.

Answer (score 0):

No, the magnitude may remain same, but the direction of both the velocity and centripetal acceleration changes by time.